# Property of stress-tensor in flat spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

Let $T_{ab}$ be a stress-tensor in a flat space satisfying conservation equations. Define
$$
P^i=\int T^{oi}d^3x, \;\; D^i=\int T^{00}x^id^3x
$$

Can anyone show me how to prove
$$
\frac{dD^i}{dt}=P^i
$$

and
$$
\frac{dP^i}{dt}=0
$$
?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99444/2451

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with second equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dP^i}{dt} = \partial_0 \int T^{0i} d^3x = - \int \partial_j T^{ji} d^3x = -\oint_S n_jT^{ji} d^2x=0
\end{equation}

First, the definition of $P^i$ is used, then conservation of stress-energy tensor $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0=\partial_0 T^{0\nu}+\partial_j T^{j\nu}$ (with $\nu=i$), then the Gauss theorem, and finally the assumption that stress-energy tensor vanishes in infinity.

Similarly, for first equation one gets:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dD^i}{dt} &=& \partial_0 \int T^{00}x^i d^3x 
\\&=& \int (\partial_0 T^{00})x^i d^3x 
\\&=& -\int (\partial_j T^{j0})x^i d^3x
\\&=& -\int [\partial_j (T^{j0}x^i)] d^3x + \int T^{j0} (\partial_jx^i) d^3x
\\&=& -\oint_S n_j T^{j0}x^i d^3x + \int T^{j0} \delta^i_j d^3x
\\&=& \int T^{i0} d^3x \\&=& P^i
\end{eqnarray}